# Draw circle over the bitmap with the color same as the under bitmap

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-canvas

I have an `image`, I can draw an `circle` over it like the code below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.girl).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(200);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE.FILL);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, 100,
            paint);
```

And the `circle` will be red color! But because of some reason, I want the color of `circle` same as its under `bitmap`. Can I do it? and how? Thanks everyone!

Edited: One more question, How I can get all the pixels inside `circle`?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you simply remove the `paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE.FILL);` or try changing the `paint.setColor(Color.RED);` to Transparent color, that should be it

Comment: Actually, I want to use some effect with the `circle` which will be drawn! Such as blurring the `circle`...

Comment: try using `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);` instead of your own Style, see if it works for you

Comment: It's no use! If I try to use `paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`, there's no effect when i use `blur` for `circle`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the color of a specified `pixel` by the method in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android) and then make a `RGB Color` then set this color instead of the `color.RED` you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but how to get all the pixels inside the `circle`?