# Color from Circle ImageView

Tags: android

I create circle ImageView, next code

```
ImageView colorView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chooseColorEdit);
colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
colorView.setBackground(drawable);
```

How I get color from imageView?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16684616/3867515

Comment: @Janak Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get color like below code

```
Drawable background = colorView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
   Color color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
 }
```

Comment: @Eren_Utku sorry, my background is not ColorDrawable

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Get `ColorDrawable` from `ImageView`.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) colorView.getBackground();
```

**2.** Get `color` using:

```
colorDrawable.getColor();
```