# How To Change App Bar Color With Imageview Color?

Tags: java, android, colors

I have one notification log app,how can I change app bar color with same color of app icon.

For example i want to change app bar color from the icon image color

[image]

I am getting icon like this

```
  ImageView icon = findViewById(R.id.icon);
                icon.setImageDrawable(Util.getAppIconFromPackage(this, packageName));
```

So How can I get color from image view and change it to app bar color

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684289/android-get-color-from-imageview-with-colorfilter-applied-to-drawable this

Comment: But wait, you have a dynamic app icon? I mean, when you set the app icon, you see the color, don't you? Why do you want to set it dnamically?

Comment: i tried using Palettete lib to get color

Comment: but how can i get imageview as bitmap res.   ImageView icon = findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageDrawable(Util.getAppIconFromPackage(this, packageName));

       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), icon.getDrawable());

Comment: I think you did not get what I try to ask, why do you have to get the app icon color?

Comment: I want to change app bar color with the same color of the app icon i get

Comment: Is that possible in android ?

Comment: So let's start it over, so, for some reason, do you want to set the app at color dnamically. And you stuck at getting bitmap from imageview. My first question is, when you tried to search for getting imageview bitmap, what did you got? What was the error? My second question is, if you got the icon, don't you se the color of icon? I mean, with your eyes, the app icon won't change I dnamically, I assume.

Comment: i did it, i have posted answer :)

Comment: I'm still curious with my second part of the question :-P

Comment: Its a notification Log app, so everytime i get a new icon, so getting color from icon and then adding to app bar

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!

Add This Gradle

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
```

And Add This Code In Activity

```
 private void geticoncolor() {
        ImageView icon = findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageDrawable(Util.getAppIconFromPackage(this, packageName));

       //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), geticoncolor());

        Bitmap bitmap3 = ((BitmapDrawable)icon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) icon.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap2 = drawable.getBitmap();

        Palette.from(bitmap3).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                //work with the palette here
                int defaultValue = 0x000000;
                int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(defaultValue);
                int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(defaultValue);
                int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(defaultValue);
                int muted = palette.getMutedColor(defaultValue);
                int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(defaultValue);
                int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(defaultValue);

                ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(vibrant));
               // actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000099'>Hello World</font>"));

               // Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, ""+vibrant+vibrantDark+mutedLight+mutedDark, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*vibrantView.setBackgroundColor(vibrant);
                vibrantLightView.setBackgroundColor(vibrantLight);
                vibrantDarkView.setBackgroundColor(vibrantDark);
                mutedView.setBackgroundColor(muted);
                mutedLightView.setBackgroundColor(mutedLight);
                mutedDarkView.setBackgroundColor(mutedDark);*/
            }
        });


    }
```