# Detect Color Code of live android camera preview

Tags: android, colors, android-camera, color-picker

I would like to detect colorcode of image (live stream image) while camera preview is going on. I want to develop sample android application which works like [ColorGrab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loomatix.colorgrab&hl=en) android application. Please find attached screenshot for the same.

How can I make demo program application which capture and recognize colors simply by pointing the camera and show as hexcode of that color.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raj.colorwalls

Look at this app url, it should give you some idea. It uses this code:

```
int frameHeight1 = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
    int frameWidth1 = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    int rgb1[] = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
    decodeYUV420SP(rgb1, data, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, frameWidth1, frameHeight1, Config.ARGB_8888);
    int pixel = bmp1.getPixel( x,y );
    int redValue1 = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue1 = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue1 = Color.green(pixel);
    int thiscolor1 = Color.rgb(redValue1, greenValue1, blueValue1);
```

[image]

Comment: Does this code works on Android `v4.2.2` API Level: `15`? Or works on Lollipop+ versions?

Comment: Yes it works on Android L and Android M also. You can test it in other versions by installing App : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raj.colorwalls

Answer (score 0):

This should be your starting point

**Get color from image pixel touched**

```
targetImage.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener(){     
@Override   
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +       
    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);


    return true;    }     
});
```

You will get the RGB color code.

Got from [How to Get Pixel Colour in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you should try this where x and y is the pixle position

```
    int frameHeight = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
    int frameWidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    int rgb[] = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
    decodeYUV420SP(rgb, data, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, frameWidth, frameHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    int pixel = bmp.getPixel( x,y );
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
    int thiscolor = Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
```

Comment: Where are you setting or getting the 'data' value in 'decodeYUV420SP(rgb, data, frameWidth, frameHeight);'?