# How to query mbtiles database in android platform

Tags: android, osmdroid, mbtiles

I am working on an android application that has raster map stored in mbtiles. I am using osmdroid to display mbtiles maps.

Now I want to develop a feature where users can click on map and the app. extract raster value from the clicked location from mbtiles.

I have looked at "[How to Get Pixel Colour in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android)" question but not sure how it will help in my case.

I appreciate if some one can help.

thanks

Comment: do you want the on screen coordinates, the lat/lon coordinates, the color? the image itself?

Comment: I want color from clicked location. thanks for your help.