# How to determine coordinates of touch event on an imageview which has an arc and rectangle in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-touch-event

I have the following shape-image

[image]

I want to validate my touch events when I touch in the blue area or not in my imageview. I need to combine the arc and the rectangle as one and validate the coordinates of the touch event?

I use this if it was a circle

```
private boolean isIn3PointArea(float touchX, float touchY, float centerX, float centerY, double r){
    float x = touchX - centerX;
    float y = touchY - centerY;
    return (touchY < centerY && Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) > r);
}
```

Comment: This is more of a math problem than programming.

Comment: can I combine the coordinates of both shapes the rect and the arc ?

Comment: Or: get touch coordinates, get ImageView bitmap cache, call bitmap.getPixel(x,y) and verify it is *blueish*.

Comment: any example of that?

Comment: something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android

Comment: If you are sure of the color @mvai solution its the easiest.