# Extract colors at known coordinates from reference patterns

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-recognition

I have a set of colors in a card, as below (I can modify the card as required)

[image]

I have 4 reference points at four corners. I have a bunch of colors at known coordinates (in mm) from these reference points.

A user clicks a picture of this card on their phone (Android) (assume good lighting condition)

I can calibrate the distance from the number of pixels between the identified reference patterns and the known actual distance (in mm) between them.

Pixels per mm = (Number of pixels between the centers of any two reference points) / (Actual distances in mm between those two reference points)

How do I extract each of these color values from the picture on the Android phone locally?

What I thought so far:

1. Detect the reference patterns and get their coordinates.
2. I know the actual distance in mm
3. From the coordinates and actual distance, get pixels-per-mm
4. I know the actual distance in mm of each of these colors from the reference points
5. Offset by that distance for each of the colors and find the average color in a small radius around that point.

How do I achieve this through code? And particularly on Android.

Comment: do you have the coordinates of each square's position? (x,y)?

Comment: Yes, I have the coordinates in mm

Comment: Maybe this is helpful - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android

Comment: The coordinates of each color on the card can vary since it is an image taken on a phone. The relative coordinates from the reference points at the corners is fixed.