# How to get a Pixel Color (with Pixel Coordinate)?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I think of an application Program that will give RGB color of the given coordinate I use these codes, but when I add bitmap code, the program becomes corrupted and shuts down.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editTextInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
}

public void startService(View v) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(50,50);
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
    if(pixel == Color.MAGENTA){
        Log.d("myTag", "Color Message");
    }
    String input = "Foregraund Message";
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);

}

public void stopService(View v) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Pixel Color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-color-in-android)

Comment: I Already Used This Code. But Not Work :(