# Android not recognizing Bitmap.getColor, something about version, why is this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap

I am trying to get the color value of a particular pixel in a Bitmap object.
I have the following function in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private boolean isCenterWhitePixel(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Color color = bitmap.getColor(150, 150);
    int[] rgbValues = { (int) color.red(), (int) color.green(), (int) color.blue()};
    if (rgbValues[0] == 255 && rgbValues[1] == 255 && rgbValues[2] == 255) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: the line `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)` was added to the top because on the line `Color color = bitmap.getColor(150, 150);` android studios' tooltip complained with the following:

`Call requires API level Q (current min is 23): android.graphics.Bitmap#getColor`

So I followed what android studio suggested as a solution and added that `@RequiresAPI` line.
As a result I got the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getColor(II)Landroid/graphics/Color; in class Landroid/graphics/Bitmap; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.graphics.Bitmap' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)`

Any way to get the `Bitmap.getColor` function to work?

Comment: You can use [the `getPixel(int, int)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#getPixel(int,%20int)) instead. It returns a simple `int` value that you could use with static `Color` class methods to get the components; e.g., `int color = bimap.getPixel(150, 150);`, `int red = Color.red(color);`. However, you don't really need to grab the individual components just for that comparison. You could simply do `return (color == Color.WHITE);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getColor(1,1);
```

for more Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-color-in-android)! i think this can help

Comment: Hi Tama, Please don't link external link because external link sharing can cause sometime link expired or removed. please share the answer appropriate to user based on snippet shared.