# How to get to edge pixel of an image

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get the background color of image that I download with glide.

I think(please correct me if I'm wrong) that the best way is to get the edge pixel(top - left most, bottom - right most etc, my images are usually center image with solid background color)

I'm getting specific pixel color im my recycler view like this(based on the accepted answer here: [How to Get Pixel Color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-color-in-android)):

```
       val bitmap = (binding.image.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y)
```

My question is how can I get the edge pixel of the image so I can determine the color of the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `bitmap`, you can use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` (or just `bitmap.width` and `bitmap.height` in Kotlin) to get the X and Y coordinates of the far edges (it starts at 0 so it will be `height - 1` etc).

Then you can plug those into `getColor`

```
with(bitmap) {
    // origin (0,0) is the top left corner
    val topLeft = getColor(0, 0)
    val bottomRight = getColor(width-1, height-1)
    ....
}
```

(I used `with` to avoid going `bitmap.whatever` over and over)

---

This might not be the best way to get the actual background colour, it really depends (what if the image has a thin border?) and this could be a tricky problem! Just in case it helps, Android has the [Palette library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette) which lets you [generate a bunch of colour swatches from a Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette.Builder#Builder(android.graphics.Bitmap)), so that might be useful if you want to kind of pull out the main colours from an image and pick one